# Cocoapods sudo-less installation

Tags: cocoapods

Hi I follow this guideline for sudo-less installation https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html and I stuck on `/Users/eloy/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin/pod install`

Terminal says `[!] No Podfile found in the project directory.`
Command `gem which cocoapods` correctly shows path to cocoapds so I guess installation succeed. I tried changing paths in .profile file but it's not a problem. Please give me some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the same guidelines for sudo-less installation, and I had the same results and issues. I'm very new to all of this, so take this answer with a healthy dose of skepticism unless someone more experienced confirms it.

After some poking around on google, I stumbled upon [this article](https://tomasznazarenko.com/how-to-instal-cocoapods-on-a-mac-with-zsh-shell/).

Following these instructions resolved my issues, so I hope they help you as well.

EDIT: This temporarily adds CocoaPods to your path. I am using a Mac that uses a zsh shell for the terminal.app. I'm not sure what shell you have, but for Macs you'll need to edit your .zshrc file (or create one because you will not have a .zshrc file on your Mac if you have not created one yourself already). I found [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1518007) that shows how to create the .zshrc file through the terminal. You can find the .zshrc file you have created by navigating to Macintosh HD > Users > [INSERT_USERNAME] and pressing "cmd + shift + ." to show hidden files. Scroll down until you see the .zshrc file, open it with a text editor, and input the code from the first page I linked. Save it and exit. Now you should always have CocoaPods in your path every time you open up the terminal!

Probably an easier way to do this, but it worked for me.